# maps not created correctly with geom_scatterpie

Tags: dictionary, plot, scatterpie

I have an issue with the geom_scatterpie function.

I am using R version 4.1.1, scatterpie_0.2.1 and ggplot2_3.4.2 to create some maps with pie charts.

Unfortunately, as you can see in the attached figures, my maps are not being created correctly.
[map_try_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f78ed.png)
[map_try_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ5jR.png)

This is the script I am running

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scatterpie)

##############################################################################

lat_lon_province <- read.csv("lat_lon_province.txt", sep ="\t")
pies <- read.csv("pies.txt", sep ="\t")
colnames(pies)[colnames(pies) == "Province"] ="PROVINCE"

pies_ecoregion_lat_lon <- merge(pies, lat_lon_province, by = "PROVINCE")
pies_ecoregion_lat_lon[is.na(pies_ecoregion_lat_lon)] <- 0
colnms=c("Copepoda", "Isopoda", "Nematoda", "Cestoda", "Trematoda", "Monogenea", "Myxozoa")
pies_ecoregion_lat_lon$Total_parasites<-rowSums(pies_ecoregion_lat_lon[,colnms])

n <- nrow(pies_ecoregion_lat_lon)
pies_ecoregion_lat_lon$radius <- 6 * abs(rnorm(n))

lon_min <- 80
lon_max <- 270
lat_min <- -50
lat_max <- 50

# Using map_data()
pacific_world <- map_data("world2")

#world2MapEnv or world2
#This is an alternative version of the world database based on latitudes [0, 360), 
#which then has the Pacific Ocean in the centre of the map.
mapplot_pacific <- ggplot(pacific_world) + 
  geom_map(data = pacific_world, map = pacific_world, 
           aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=region), col = "white", fill = "gray50") + theme_bw()
mapplot_pacific + 
  coord_map(xlim=c(lon_min, lon_max), ylim=c(lat_min, lat_max)) +
  geom_scatterpie(aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, r=radius), 
                  data = pies_ecoregion_lat_lon, cols = colnames(pies_ecoregion_lat_lon[,c(3:9)]), 
                  color=NA, alpha=.8) +
  geom_scatterpie_legend(pies_ecoregion_lat_lon$radius, x=240, y=35)
ggsave("map_try_1.png", width = 10)

###############################################################################

pacific_map <- fortify(pacific_world, 
                       xlim = c(lon_min, lon_max), 
                       ylim = c(lat_min, lat_max), 
                       fill = T, plot = F)

pacific <- ggplot(pacific_map)

ggplot(pacific_map, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + geom_polygon() + 
  coord_map(xlim=c(lon_min, lon_max), ylim=c(lat_min, lat_max)) +
  geom_scatterpie(aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, group = PROVINCE, r=radius), 
                  data = pies_ecoregion_lat_lon, cols = colnames(pies_ecoregion_lat_lon[,c(3:9)]), 
                  color=NA, alpha=.8) +
  geom_scatterpie_legend(pies_ecoregion_lat_lon$radius, x=240, y=35) + 
  theme_bw()
ggsave("map_try_2.png", width = 10)
```

My input files are `pies.txt`

| Province | Fish | Copepoda | Isopoda | Nematoda | Cestoda | Monogenea | Trematoda | Myxozoa |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Eastern Coral Triangle | 3 | 24 | 6 | 4 |  |  | 2 |  |
| Java Transitional |  | 14 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Lord Howe and Norfolk Islands | 2 | 3 | 2 |  |  |  | 1 |  |
| Northeast Australian Shelf | 82 | 89 | 28 | 21 | 55 | 109 | 238 | 19 |
| Northwest Australian Shelf | 51 | 14 | 7 |  | 3 | 2 | 26 | 2 |
| Sahul Shelf | 22 | 46 | 26 | 4 | 28 | 12 | 9 |  |
| South China Sea | 563 | 24 | 62 | 2 |  | 2 |  |  |
| South Kuroshio |  | 21 | 24 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Sunda Shelf | 311 | 29 | 11 |  |  |  | 3 | 1 |
| Tropical Northwestern Pacific | 2 | 31 | 14 |  |  |  | 9 |  |
| Tropical Southwestern Pacific | 14 | 913 | 154 | 48 | 82 | 220 | 393 | 27 |
| Western Coral Triangle | 26 | 605 | 122 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Central Polynesia | 1 | 42 | 10 |  |  | 6 | 2 |  |
| Easter Island | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Hawaii | 27 | 254 | 225 | 32 | 16 | 66 | 668 | 8 |
| Marquesas | 213 | 4 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Marshall, Gilbert and Ellis Islands |  | 407 | 96 | 10 | 37 | 16 | 105 | 13 |
| Southeast Polynesia | 1041 | 8 | 36 |  | 1 | 18 | 21 |  |

and

`lat_lon_province.txt`

| PROVINCE | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Eastern Coral Triangle | -9.989942453 | 153.1554975 |
| Java Transitional | -9.398129883 | 103.2355709 |
| Lord Howe and Norfolk Islands | -30.3708992 | 163.7689972 |
| Northeast Australian Shelf | -14.61130754 | 147.613617 |
| Northwest Australian Shelf | -17.00240261 | 117.3920957 |
| Sahul Shelf | -9.727364469 | 129.9578054 |
| South China Sea | 15.50365482 | 113.5205013 |
| South Kuroshio | 23.64450073 | 127.5490036 |
| Sunda Shelf | 4.935839414 | 107.017955 |
| Tropical Northwestern Pacific | 8.891712166 | 148.0158917 |
| Tropical Southwestern Pacific | -20.82816019 | 177.8582737 |
| Western Coral Triangle | -4.840562086 | 127.5081903 |
| Central Polynesia | -9.675919844 | -164.9687772 |
| Easter Island | -26.84119987 | -107.4769974 |
| Hawaii | 22.68499947 | -163.0189972 |
| Marquesas | -9.251319885 | -139.6159973 |
| Marshall, Gilbert and Ellis Islands | 4.272244259 | 171.2996466 |
| Southeast Polynesia | -20.34943869 | -159.067165 |

Can you let me know if you have any idea why this is happening?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a CRS issue and not a `scatterpie` issue. Similar errors are mentioned in other GIS related questions like [Appropriate map projection for the Pacific Ocean](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138735/appropriate-map-projection-for-the-pacific-ocean), [How to change map projection from pacific to Atlantic centered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71929397/how-to-change-map-projection-from-pacific-to-atlantic-centered), [Reprojecting over the Pacific Ocean with EPSG:3832 gives artefacts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371693/reprojecting-over-the-pacific-ocean-with-epsg3832-gives-artefacts).

For the pacific ocean maps the CRS most commonly used is the [EPSG:3832](https://epsg.io/3832), but as mentioned [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229060/shapefile-not-displayed-after-changing-projection-from-epsg4326-to-epsg3832-in)

> the scope of the EPSG:3832 is not for global mapping and its area use can be seen at - http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3832/

So in order to avoid this, first transform a global map to EPSG:3832 and then make valid to neglect the inconsistency.

In R with the sf package this is done with functions `st_transform` and `st_make_valid`. And then with `st_crop`, crop the map to the desired extend.
Here is the script with the

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(spData) # for the shapefiles of world
library(scatterpie)

##############################################################################
### load user data and transformations ####
lat_lon_province <- read.csv("lat_lon_province.txt", sep ="\t")
pies <- read.csv("pies.txt", sep ="\t")
colnames(pies)[colnames(pies) == "Province"] ="PROVINCE"

pies_ecoregion_lat_lon <- merge(pies, lat_lon_province, by = "PROVINCE")
pies_ecoregion_lat_lon[is.na(pies_ecoregion_lat_lon)] <- 0
colnms=c("Copepoda", "Isopoda", "Nematoda", "Cestoda", "Trematoda", "Monogenea", "Myxozoa")
pies_ecoregion_lat_lon$Total_parasites<-rowSums(pies_ecoregion_lat_lon[,colnms])

## trasform to sf odject and assign CRS
pies_sf <- st_as_sf(pies_ecoregion_lat_lon, coords=c("Longitude","Latitude"),crs = st_crs("WGS84"))

## transform to EPSG:3832 to match the pacific ocean CRS
pies_sf_3832 <- st_transform(pies_sf, "EPSG:3832")

## make data frame again because the geom_scatterpie doesn't accept sf objects
pies_sf_3832$Longitude  <- st_coordinates(pies_sf_3832)[,1]
pies_sf_3832$Latitude  <- st_coordinates(pies_sf_3832)[,2]
pies_sf_3832_df <- st_drop_geometry(pies_sf_3832)
pies_sf_3832_df$radius <- pies_sf_3832_df$Total_parasites*500

### Load map data from spData and transformations

world <- world # use the spData \


## transform to EPSG:3832 to match the pacific ocean CRS
world_pacific <- st_transform(world, "EPSG:3832") 
## its important to make valid because there are some values 
## in the polygons that go to infinity
world_pacific <- st_make_valid(world_pacific)

## The scope of the EPSG:3832 is not for global mapping 
## therefore keep only the desired area
world_pacific_crop <- st_crop(world_pacific, xmin=-10387065, ymin=-11225295, xmax=19953635, ymax=9906424 )


## plot
##
map_world_pacific_sf <- ggplot() +
    geom_sf(world_pacific_crop, mapping=aes()) +
    geom_sf(pies_sf_3832,  mapping=aes()) +
    geom_label(data = pies_sf_3832_df, 
               mapping=aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, label = PROVINCE),
               size = 1.5,
               nudge_x = 1000000,
               nudge_y = 100000)+
    geom_scatterpie(aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, r=radius), 
                  data = pies_sf_3832_df,
                  cols = colnames(pies_sf_3832_df[,c(3:9)]),
                  color=NA, alpha=.8) + 
    geom_scatterpie_legend(pies_sf_3832_df$Total_parasites*500,
                           x=-5205792.4,
                           y=-7529715.0) +
    theme_bw()

ggsave("map_pacific_pie_1.png", width = 10, plot=map_world_pacific_sf)
```

[Pacific Ocean map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb5pS.png)

Note that the aesthetics of radius and legend of `geom_scatterpie` need some tweaking to get them to the desired form.